# Proper configuring of 301 redirects for SEO compliance?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

After a lot of research and help from SO members, I have cleared my first major hurdle with .htaccess.

My new .htaccess file successfully renames my `index.php` page to `/home` and takes all of the query strings attached to the links:

`http://www.website.com/departments?nav=business` (etc.)

and turns them into the format I want:

`http://www.website.com/business`

Here is my .htaccess code:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/?Home/?$ /index.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-?]+)/?$ departments.php?nav=$1 [L]
```

If any of the above code isn't ideal, I've collected it in my research online and I'm still learning from it.

My question is, now that I have redefined the links, I know I should do a 301 redirect so that the old links don't show up as duplicates or some such with the search engines. I apologize up front for not having all the lingo down, but this is a long day two of research on this.

What is the proper code to add in order to do the redirect to keep the page SEO friendly?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make you RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-?]+)/?$ departments.php?nav=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Which will make your links do a 301 redirect to your new URLs.

Comment: That's all there is to it? Wow, MANY thanks for that! :)

Comment: After deploying this code, although the link says, `http://www.website.com/business' when it is moused-over, it still opens `http://www.website.com/departments?nav=business` in the address window. Is this because the new links need to cache or some other such anomaly?

Comment: .htaccess won't change the links in your code, you need to update your app to point to the new URLs.  All it will do is redirect any of the old URLs to the new ones.

Comment: Update my App? If you wouldn't mind elaborating, I'd appreciate it. The links in my navbar are as they should be. It was working fine on my test site, then when the code was finished I uploaded it to the site I am working on. That's when this started happening. Even the address bar on the test site showed the old links. I have since removed the code from the test site and it is now only flying on the live site. Weird.